# naming collision in namespaces in modules of python

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, module

```
# module1.py

question = "What is the meaning of life, the Universe, and everything?"
answer = 42


# module2.py

question = "What is your quest?"
answer = "To seek the holy grail."




>>> import module1
>>> import module2
>>> print module1.question
What is the meaning of life, the Universe, and everything?
>>> print module2.question
What is your quest?
>>> print module1.answer
42
>>> print module2.answer
To seek the holy grail.
```

If we had used from module1 import * and from module2 import * instead, we would have a naming collision and would not be able to access question and answer from module1. Why is it so ?

Comment: Because `*` imports everything into module's current namespace.

Comment: This is a **major** reason ***not*** to use `from module import *`!

Comment: [From docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules): Note that in general the practice of importing `*` from a module or package is **frowned** upon, since it often causes poorly readable code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple example based on @alexce's example:

```
>>> pi = 22/7
>>> pi
3
```

Variables currently defined in global namespace:

```
>>> vars()
{'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__', 'pi': 3, '__doc__': None, '__package__': None}
```

Now we do a `*` based import:

```
>>> from math import *
```

New `pi` from `math` replaces old `pi`

```
>>> pi
3.141592653589793
```

Now the global namespace is filled with math module's variables:

```
>>> vars()
{'pow': <built-in function pow>, 'fsum': <built-in function fsum>, 'cosh': <built-in function cosh>, 'ldexp': <built-in function ldexp>, 'hypot': <built-in function hypot>, 'acosh': <built-in function acosh>, 'tan': <built-in function tan>, 'asin': <built-in function asin>, 'isnan': <built-in function isnan>, 'log': <built-in function log>, 'fabs': <built-in function fabs>, 'floor': <built-in function floor>, 'atanh': <built-in function atanh>, 'sqrt': <built-in function sqrt>, '__package__': None, 'frexp': <built-in function frexp>, 'factorial': <built-in function factorial>, 'degrees': <built-in function degrees>, 'pi': 3.141592653589793, 'log10': <built-in function log10>, '__doc__': None, 'asinh': <built-in function asinh>, 'fmod': <built-in function fmod>, 'atan': <built-in function atan>, '__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, 'copysign': <built-in function copysign>, 'cos': <built-in function cos>, 'ceil': <built-in function ceil>, 'atan2': <built-in function atan2>, 'isinf': <built-in function isinf>, 'sinh': <built-in function sinh>, '__name__': '__main__', 'trunc': <built-in function trunc>, 'expm1': <built-in function expm1>, 'e': 2.718281828459045, 'tanh': <built-in function tanh>, 'radians': <built-in function radians>, 'sin': <built-in function sin>, 'lgamma': <built-in function lgamma>, 'erf': <built-in function erf>, 'erfc': <built-in function erfc>, 'modf': <built-in function modf>, 'exp': <built-in function exp>, 'acos': <built-in function acos>, 'log1p': <built-in function log1p>, 'gamma': <built-in function gamma>}
```

So, such import will replace all variables with the same name that were already defined in global namespace.

From [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules):

> Note that in general the practice of importing `*` from a module or
>   package is **frowned** upon, since it often causes poorly readable code.
>   However, it is okay to use it to save typing in interactive sessions.

Answer (score 2):

```
x = 'foo'
x = 'bar'
print x
```

That's why.

Comment: Short answer - perfect answer.